# Timeout context manager should be used inside a task discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

My understanding of this error is that it is complaining that it is not in an async def function. However, mine is and I even used `loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()` followed by `loop.run_until_complete(onInfoAsync(info,conn))`. Here is the error:

```
Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
  File "C:\Users\ianfi\Documents\pythonStuff\PyQt5\ServerCalling\main.py", line 42, in onInfoAsync
    dm = await member.create_dm()
  File "C:\Users\ianfi\Documents\pythonStuff\PyQt5\ServerCalling\main.py", line 57, in onInfo
    loop.run_until_complete(onInfoAsync(info,conn))
```

as you can see in the error, it tracebacks to `loop.run_until_complete(onInfoAsync(info,conn))` which puts it in a task. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and if you need more information, dont hesitate to ask, I'm new to stack overflow.

Here's some other stuff I tried:
I found online that doing `asyncio.get_event_loop()` instead of making a new one might fix it, but it just errors saying that there is no loop to get. I have also tried using `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)` but that did not change the results.

Thanks for any help!

Edit:
I have tried some more things and made a kind of middleman function.

```
async def between(info:str, conn):
    task = asyncio.create_task(onInfoAsync(info,conn))
    await task
```

although the error was complaining about it not being in a task (which it very obviously is now), it still errors. Here is the traceback with this function in place:

```
Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
  File "C:\Users\ianfi\Documents\pythonStuff\PyQt5\ServerCalling\main.py", line 51, in onInfoAsync
    dm = await member.create_dm()
  File "C:\Users\ianfi\Documents\pythonStuff\PyQt5\ServerCalling\main.py", line 36, in between
    await task
  File "C:\Users\ianfi\Documents\pythonStuff\PyQt5\ServerCalling\main.py", line 75, in onInfo
    loop.run_until_complete(between(info,conn))
```

Comment: You shouldn't make another event loop because discord already has one. Also why are you trying to create a task and then await it? Why not await the coroutine directly?

Comment: Im not quite sure how I can use discord's event loop. Im making one because its in a thread (not the main one). I tried to put it in a task and await it for 2 reasons. 1: Im sick of this bug and I'm willing to try anything. 2: the error is saying that it needs to be used inside a **task** so I decided to wrap it in a task, just in case.

Comment: I found out how to get discord.py's event loop, and I used that and now it works!!! Sadly, it's really delayed now but that's probably because discord must be having a lot of things running behind the scenes in that loop...

Comment: @EricJin now, I use ``task = client.loop.create_task(onInfoAsync(info,conn))``, but every time I run this, it takes even longer to start onInfoAsync. I tried adding a print as the very first line of onInfoAsync and it takes about 30 seconds for it to run after the task is created. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This probably won't do anything, but try using `asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task` to put it in the actual event loop. Do you have any non-async blocking things in your code?

Comment: I did that and it is just as slow...

Comment: What does `onInfoAsync` do? What libraries are you using (for example, `requests` can block asyncio)?

Answer (score 2):

Discord.py has the same issue as Hikari: it won't let you make async API calls outside of the event loop it started. Creating new loops or calling discord without using its loop will inevitably make you hit that error. I hit it many times before I learned how to use their event loop outside of async functions. You have to use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro, loop)`. Also, `asyncio.get_event_loop()` will always fail outside of an async function, and `asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)` won't work unless it's discord's loop. I was able to get `asyncio.create_task(coro)` to work, but only if it's called from an async function on their event loop.

If your code is running slowly, you could create a separate thread and pass in the loop as an arg:

```py
import threading
import asyncio
import discord

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop() 
        threading.Thread(target=self.separate_thread, args=[loop]).start()

    def separate_thread(self, loop):
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(self.my_async_func(), loop)
    
    async def my_async_func(self):
        app_info = await self.application_info()
        print(f'bot name: {app_info.name}')

intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = MyClient(intents=intents)
client.run('YOUR_TOKEN')
```