# How do I run a discord py bot asynchronously with another async function?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to run in one thread, and I want an async function to run in another. This async function will basically check if it is 2 pm, and send messages to all the servers it is in. If it is not 2 pm, the thread will sleep.

I tried many ways, but I was unable to run the bot correctly in a thread.

Tried this simple approach using threading

```py
        import threading
        sync_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN,))
        async_thread = threading.Thread(target=asyncio.run, args=(self.start_alerts() ,))

        sync_thread.start()
        async_thread.start()

        # Wait for both threads to complete
        sync_thread.join()
        async_thread.join()
```

But it gives the following error on this line. I'm getting this error not just on `fetch_user` but on any bot operation like sending message to a channel.

```py
admin = await self.fetch_user(DISCORD_ADMIN_ID)
```

```
 File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 2525, in fetch_user
    data = await self.http.get_user(user_id)
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 624, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1141, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 467, in _request
    with timer:
  File "/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 701, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
 RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that solves this issue. Adding it here instead of deleting the question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73903794/11721258